# Any Difference Between "Auxiliary Verb"
And "Modal Verb"?

Tags: grammar

Are they the same thing, just one meaning with two vocabulary items?

Comment: From Merriam-Webster: [*The auxiliary verbs (which include **be, have, do,** and the modal verbs like **may, shall, will, can,** and **must**) combine with verbs to do things like show a verb's tense or form a question. We'll look at the modal verbs on the next page, and deal with **be, have** and **do** here.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/auxiliary-transitive-intransitive-modal-and-other-types-of-verbs/auxiliary-verbs) So that link should explain things for you.

Comment: Modal verbs behave as auxiliary verbs in that they help form the interrogative and negative of sentences but, unlike *be, have, do*, which are only auxiliaries (except in the forms *be to, have to*, modal verbs also express modalities like permission, ability, possibility, obligation, deduction, necessity, advice, etc.

Comment: Modals are a subtype of auxiliary verb. Unlike the non-modal auxiliaries ("be", "have" and "do"), they are used to mark **mood**.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these groups of verbs is in their meanings.

Auxiliaries have the  formal (grammatical) meaning.

Modals have the modal (lexical) meaning.

From the functional point of view they are similar.

Sometimes modals are termed 'modal auxiliaries'.